# rake paperclip:refresh db conection error

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm using Rails and paperclip and trying to run`

```
rake paperclip:refresh class=Model_Name_Goes_Here
```

but I get the error

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user roy
```

I can run other rake tasks fine, I expect they are using the database user specified in my database.yml file. Why isn't this paperclip rake task using my database.yml file, instead its trying to connect using the unix user I'm logged in as. Even so this user has all privileges and I can access the database using psql.
I've also tried setting the unix domain socket connections to

```
local all         all                 trust
```

in the pg_hba.conf  file. which didn't help.

Any suggestions on how to run this rake task?

Edit:
I solved this by writing my own rask task

```
 Model.find_each{|m| m.attachment.reprocess! if m.attachment}
```

Comment: `local` is for connections through Unix sockets. I assume Rails connects through JDBC and therefor you need a line starting with `host` to allow connections through TCP.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried host all all the_machines_ip_address/32 trust and it didn't make a difference